# Error in transforming XML Document into HTML using XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, atom-editor

I am transforming an XML document into HTML using XSLT.
And i get this error code:

```
TypeError: Failed to execute 'serializeToString' on 'XMLSerializer': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
    at AtomXsltransformView.module.exports.AtomXsltransformView.doTransform (file:///C:/Users/X/.atom/packages/atom-xsltransform/lib/atom-xsltransform-view.coffee:86:19)
    at AtomXsltransformView.module.exports.AtomXsltransformView.transform (file:///C:/Users/X/.atom/packages/atom-xsltransform/lib/atom-xsltransform-view.coffee:66:22)
    at HTMLDivElement.atom.commands.add.core:confirm (file:///C:/Users/X/.atom/packages/atom-xsltransform/lib/atom-xsltransform-view.coffee:19:27)
    at CommandRegistry.handleCommandEvent (C:\Users\X\appdata\local\atom\app-1.55.0\resources\app\static\<embedded>:11:350382)
    at KeymapManager.dispatchCommandEvent (C:\Users\X\appdata\local\atom\app-1.55.0\resources\app\static\<embedded>:11:1230982)
    at KeymapManager.handleKeyboardEvent (C:\Users\X\appdata\local\atom\app-1.55.0\resources\app\static\<embedded>:11:1227116)
    at WindowEventHandler.handleDocumentKeyEvent (C:\Users\X\appdata\local\atom\app-1.55.0\resources\app\static\<embedded>:11:284879)
```

**And this is my transform.xsl:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <title>Food</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div>
          <table class="table">

            <tr>
              <th>ID</th>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>
                Category
              </th>
              <th>Price</th>
            </tr>

            <xsl:for-each select="data/menus/row/">
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <xsl:value-of select="id"/></td>
                <td>
                  <xsl:value-of select="dtype"/></td>
                <td>
                  <xsl:value-of select="name"/></td>
                <td>
                  <xsl:value-of select="category"/></td>
              </tr>

            </xsl:for-each>
          </table>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I read about serializetoString() here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLSerializer/serializeToString

They suggest to use this code one:
xmlString = anXMLSerializer.serializeToString(rootNode);

I dont know if i have probably to use this proposed code or another one? If I have to use this one, how can i implement it in my xsl-sheet.Thanks for helping.

Comment: Can you show us both a minimal XML input in addition to a minimal XSLT stylesheet causing that error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XSLT code in `<xsl:for-each select="data/menus/row/">` has a syntax error, the trailing slash doesn't belong there, you need `<xsl:for-each select="data/menus/row">`.

Comment: oh wow that worked. Thank you soo much! Kind regards, S.